# while loop returns one additional empty row

Tags: bash, postgresql

I am attempting to write a bash script that list the tables in my local postgres db

```
while read line
do 
   myarray+=("$line")
   ## debug
   echo $line
done  < <(psql -h ... -U ... -t -c "select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='myschema' ;")
```

I have created 36 tables but the above code outputs a 37th line that is completely blank. I checked the number of elements like so `echo ${#myarray[@]}` ; 37 elements.

If I run the query `select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='myschema' ;`, I get 36 records back.

I am using the process substitution approach in the `while` loop as it seems faster but I think the error comes from there. Any ideas?

Comment: The loop seems like overkill. Can't you just say `myarray=($(psql ...))`?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `psql`? Does it have two newlines at the end or maybe \r\n? Can you post the output of `psql ... | hd` (hex dump)?

Comment: Unless you're expecting blank lines in the middle of the output (and you want to keep them), then you could just add (warning: bashism) `[[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && continue` at the top of the loop.

Comment: Try to use `psql -c "copy (<your query>) to stdout;"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres code, there is `fputc('\n', fout);` added as a final unconditional step, for all output formats, so you need to filter it out, e.g.:

```
while read line
do 
   myarray+=("$line")
   ## debug
   echo $line
done  < <(psql -h ... -U ... -t -c "select distinct table_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='myschema' ;" \
           | egrep -v "^$")
```

Also, keep in mind, that if in the future, you (or your colleague) will put something to `~/.psqlrc` (for example, `\timing on`) it might break your code. To protect from it, use psql's option `--no-psqlrc` (or `-X`).

Comment: Wow. That makes complete sense. Accepted and voted up. Thank you!